# Como fazer com que o número de execuções de um algoritmo seja função da capacidade de processamento e não do tempo?

Tags: python, desempenho, whatsapp

Eu escrevi um pequeno programa para enviar mensagem no whatsapp do meu Pai para lembrá-lo de tomar os remédios dele. Abaixo apresento o código que pode ser replicado por qualquer pessoa com um número de celular e um registro no API do twilio., além da planilha `medications.csv` (ver abaixo)

Meu problema é: quero que meu Pai receba uma única mensagem para cada remédio no banco de dados `medications.csv`, mas não sei como especificar isso. A *hackish solution* que encontrei foi especificar o segundo exato em que a mensagem deve ser enviada. Contudo, creio que deve existir uma solução melhor já que se o programa rodar em um PC mais rápido que o meu é provável que o teste lógico e o loop rodem em velocidade superior a meio segundo, caso em que meu Pai receberia n mensagens iguais (onde n é o número de operações completas por segundo).

Como faço para esse algoritmo rodar apenas uma vez independente da capacidade de hardware?

```
from twilio.rest import Client
import pandas as pd 
from datetime import datetime
import re
from time import sleep

account_sid = '' #insira seu sid aqui
auth_token = '' #insira seu token aqui
client = Client(account_sid, auth_token)

def to_list_integer(dt_time):
    return [dt_time.year,dt_time.month,dt_time.day, dt_time.hour,dt_time.minute]



df=pd.read_csv('medications.csv')

while True:
    data_lista =  to_list_integer(datetime.now())
    x=datetime(*data_lista)
    hora = x.strftime("%Hh%M")
    for i in range(len(df)):
        if (datetime.now().hour==df['hour'][i]) & (datetime.now().minute==5) & (datetime.now().second==1):
            text = '''*Lembrete: {0}*\n
Olá sr(a). Fulano, agora são {1}, 
\nestá na hora de tomar {2} comprimido(s) de {0}
\n\n*recomendação médica: {3}*'''.format(df['name'][i],hora,re.search(r'\d+',df['recomendation'][i]).group(),
                                                df['recomendation'][i])
            for person in ['whatsapp:+55XXXXXXXXXXX','whatsapp:+XXXXXXXXXXX']:#insira o seu número e do familiar aqui. Oseu é apenas pra controlar
                message = client.messages.create(
                                            body=text,
                                            from_='whatsapp:+XXXXXXXXXXX',#insira seu número twilio aqui
                                            to=person
                                        )
            print(message.sid)
```

`medications.csv`:

```
name,dosage,recomendation,hour,minute
remédio 1,100mg,Tomar 1 comprimido pela manhã,6,9
remédio 1 Plus,20/12.5 mg,Tomar 1 comprimido pela manhã,6,10
remédio 1 XR,500mg,Tomar 2 comprimidos após o café e após a última refeição da noite,7,10
remédio 2,75mg,Tomar 1 comprimido após o almoço,16,5
remédio 3,100mg,Tomar 1 comprimido após o almoço,16,6
remédio 1,10mg,Tomar 2 comprimidos à noite,20,10
remédio 1 XR,500mg,Tomar 2 comprimidos após o café e após a última refeição da noite,20,11
Rosuvastatina,20mg,Tomar 1 comprimido após a última refeição da noite,20,12
```

> **P.S:** Foi difícil sumarizar minha dúvida no título da pergunta. Aceito sugestões para torná-lo mais claro e objetivo

Answer (score 1):

Olá, você pediu ideias e sugestões. Mas seu código não está muito claro pelo menos pra mim.
Mas pelo que entendi você quer uma rotina que chame uma função em horas pré determinadas no dia uma única vez correto? A rotina que eu consegui imaginar pra isso foi essa.

```
import pandas as pd
import time

T = pd.Timestamp.today()
print(T)
hora1 = pd.Timestamp(T.year, T.month,T.day, T.hour,T.minute,20)
hora2 = pd.Timestamp(T.year, T.month,T.day, T.hour,T.minute,30)
hora3 = pd.Timestamp(T.year, T.month,T.day, T.hour,T.minute,40)

hora_reset = pd.Timestamp(T.year, T.month,T.day, 23,59,55)

d = {'Horário': [hora1,hora2,hora3], 'Controle':[False,False,False],'Lembretes': ['Remedio1', 'Remedio2', 'Remedio1']}

while True:
    t = pd.Timestamp.now()
    for x in range(len(d['Horário'])):
        if (t > d['Horário'][x] ) and (d['Controle'][x] == False):
            print(d['Lembretes'][x])
            d['Controle'][x] = True
        if (t > hora_reset):
            d['Horário'][0] = pd.Timestamp(t.year, t.month,(t.day+1), 8,0,0)
            d['Horário'][1] = pd.Timestamp(t.year, t.month,(t.day+1), 12,0,0)
            d['Horário'][2] = pd.Timestamp(t.year, t.month,(t.day+1), 16,0,0)
            hora_reset = pd.Timestamp(t.year, t.month,(t.day+1), 23,59,55)
            d['Lembretes'][0] = False
            d['Lembretes'][1] = False
            d['Lembretes'][2] = False
    time.sleep(1)
```

No caso o programa printa a mensagem nos próximos 20, 30 e 40 segundos para testar, mas se você alterar as linhas de definição das horas para 8h00, 12h00, 16h00, etc. Fica assim:

```
hora1 = pd.Timestamp(T.year, T.month,T.day, 8,0,0)
hora2 = pd.Timestamp(T.year, T.month,T.day, 12,0,0)
hora3 = pd.Timestamp(T.year, T.month,T.day, 16,0,0)
```

> Como faço para esse algoritmo rodar apenas uma vez independente da
>   capacidade de hardware?

Acredito que a resposta para isso é a função `time.sleep()` que está no código. No caso ela provoca um delay de 'x' segundos em cada loop do while e você pode ajusta para como ficar melhor para sua aplicação e economizar processamento do computador. No caso de remédios vc pode ter um delay de 60 até uns 300 segundos que é bem aceitável.

Comment: Interessante. Logo mais vou olhar com calma sua solução. Sobre seu último ponto, inicialmente utilizei a `time.sleep()`, mas ela entra no mesmo problema: fixar o tempo, de delay ou de execução, não garante que computadores diferentes façam um mesmo número de operações dentro do `for loop`

Comment: O número de operações dentro de um loop é determinado pelo código dentro do loop. O tempo de execução que é definido pelo hardware. Qualquer computador roda esse loop em milisegundos ou até menos. Além disso eu não vejo pq você acha que o tempo de execução é algo crítico para o seu programa. Se vc olhar o código vai ver que o disparo acontece quando 'now()' é maior que o tempo do disparo, se vc usar sem delay, o disparo ocorre apenas milisegundos dps que passou a hora oq eu acho que resolve bem o seu problema. E vc consegue garantir que o disparo é único pela variável de controle.

Comment: No caso do meu `for loop` o número de operações depende de quantas operações o PC faz enquanto a condicional permanece verdadeira. Para entender melhor o que estou querendo dizer, rode meu código sem especificar os segundos. Como a condição de `if (datetime.now().hour==df['hour'][i]) & (datetime.now().minute==5)` será verdadeira por um minuto inteiro, o PC realizará a operação dentro do `for loop` um número `n` de vezes, mas esse `n` vai depender da capacidade de processamento do computador. Note que especificar os `segundos` não resolve o problema, apenas diminui a média de `n`.

Comment: muito obrigado pela sua ajuda. Infelizmente, eu não fui suficiente claro. Penso que o melhor a fazer é apagar essa pergunta e fazer uma outra com um exemplo mínimo replicável e apresentando o que estou pensando de forma abstrata com algumas equações simples. Logo o farei

Comment: Agora entendi o que você quis dizer. Justamente por esse problema de fixar uma igualdade de hora.  Que eu sugeri uma estrutura de controle com desigualdade > e uma variável booleana de controle para garantir o disparo único.

Comment: Caso você tenha interesse, veja a discussão da pergunta que fiz no stack americano: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60555797/how-can-i-make-the-number-of-runs-of-an-infinite-algorithm-fixed-regardless-of-m Eu tentei fazer aqui, mas fecharam